# Changing the default timeout of Spring Kafka replying template

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are using AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate for sending and recieving a reply of messages.

I want to increase the timeout. But it seems the Kafka Listener is timing out in this case in around 30-40 seconds.

I have tried increasing the default timeout to 10 mins (just for testing ). But it did not help

```
aggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate.setDefaultReplyTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(600)); //changing the default timeout
```

Code when we are sending the message

```
private final AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, T, R> aggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate;

public RequestReplyFuture<String, T, Collection<ConsumerRecord<String, R>>> sendAndReceive(String producerTopic, T record, Headers headers) {
    ProducerRecord<String, T> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord(producerTopic, record);
    addHeaders(producerRecord, headers);
    return this.aggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(producerRecord);
}
```

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Show, please, how you use that `AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate`. The default timeout is like this anyway: `Duration DEFAULT_REPLY_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofSeconds(FIVE)`

Comment: @ArtemBilan thanks for the reply...added the code of how i send the message. The timeout above is set in a bean..

Comment: OK. Then it is time for you to share with us a simple project to let us to reproduce and play with. I cannot determine how that is possible yet.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible; it can't spontaneously time out - the timeout is scheduled; maybe put a breakpoint in `scheduleTimeout` (in the super class) to see that it is the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

I was using DeferredResult for async request with a timeout which was causing my original HTTP request to time out. This HTTP request was internally using ReplyingTemplate to communicate with the downstream services.

I did increase the ReplyingTemplate's default timeout as i mentioned above.

So, its working now.